# CSS breaks in heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am newbie in Heroku. 
When I run this rails application locally, its works fine and when I deployed to heroku its breaks. 
Please see the image. I pointed arrow inside that image.

---

Works fine locally here and its suppose to work this way. 
[image]

---

CSS breaks image here and not suppose to be like this. Only happens in Heroku server.
[image]

---

I have multiple CSS files inside the rails application, about 9 of them.
 
I am using Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3

I have been trying to fix this issue and searched for this solution everywhere but no luck.
It was working fine before, but I don't know how its happen?

Any help is appreciated, I will mark the answer as correct if it is solved.

thanks!

Update: 
when I do git push heroku, this is what i saw:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_9a6529a8-57cd-4fb0-9cc0-39ebfcdb2c7a/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_9a6529a8-57cd-4fb0-9cc0-39ebfcdb2c7a/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_9a6529a8-57cd-4fb0-9cc0-39ebfcdb2c7a/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_9a6529a8-57cd-4fb0-9cc0-39ebfcdb2c7a/Rakefile:7)
       Asset precompilation completed (105.95s)
```

Inside the application.css, I see

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/

/* rest of file omitted */
```

Comment: what is the output of `heroku logs`?  and what do you get any errors on `git push heroku`?

Comment: nope no errors on logs. All i see is depreciation warning --> 
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

Comment: that's not a big deal...are your assets precompiled?

Comment: @dax I saw this log when I did heroku push. See the edited post above.

Comment: Does it work fine in production-mode on your local-machine?

Comment: @AlexandrYakubenko yes it does work fine.

Comment: Hm, have you cleared you browser-cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably related to the asset pipeline.

Make sure all your assets are required by application.css or added to

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

in application.rb.

The assets compile in runtime locally but not in production.

EDIT: For active_admin to play nice don't include it in the application.css, i.e.: remove the

```
require_tree .
```

and require each file/directory separately.

Comment: Inside the application.css, I see require_self and require_tree, does that do the job or do I still need put that line inside my application.rb ?

Comment: That should do the job. Do you have .css or .css.scss files?

Comment: Are you using active_admin or bootstrap? You may need to explicitly add those files like so:

    config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.js', 'active_admin.css']

Comment: I am using active_admin, but activeadmin works fine. that screenshot is NON-activeadmin page

Comment: Well the pagination and search styling looks like active_admin. Make sure you are not accidentally using active_admin's styles and if you do want to use them, make sure the active_admin's styles are available on that page...

Comment: I am not using active_admin's styles. Inside the stylesheets folder there are jquery.ui.css, 960-16_col.css, active_admin,css.scss, application.css, name2.css. jequery.merow.css, jquery.tagsinput.css, reset.css and text.css

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38633/discussion-between-machine-and-jiten-k)